# Magento2: Requested product doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, product, frontend-error

When I click on add to cart button product not added and redirect to product view page. Got the error message **Requested product doesn't exist**

Comment: Can you try to after clear cache ?

Comment: I have tried after clear cache. Got the same issue @PayalPatel

Comment: Can you please check in database that if there sku in those products.?

Comment: Product SKu also there. Error showing ***customer-data.js*** in the console. @Mayur